# CodeIgniter and Old-style PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I have a domain, let's say somedomain.com.  I have an admin page somedomain.com/admin.  The pages were coded in plain PHP.  I recently re-wrote somedomain.com in CodeIgniter.  But I do not want to touch somedomain.com/admin for now.

How do I make this work?  When I go to somedomain.com/admin, it is looking an admin controller, which of course does not exist.  I have an index.php file in admin folder, I cannot figure out a way to access the index file.

Thank you.

Comment: What are your htaccess rules? Are you using Apache? If the directory exists you should be able to access that with the path (/admin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post .htaccess for us to se. But anyway. You should exclude "admin" to be directed to index.php

something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(ACT=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%1 [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(admin|index.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|thirdparty|admin|themes|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```